# How do I insert multiple rows of data into the spyder console?

Tags: python, input, console, spyder

I want to insert a large test into the console

Аnd not read from a file

```
3
3
Russian
English
Japanese
2
Russian
English
1
English
```

but in Spyder:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNNhk.png)

Аnd you have to enter data line by line. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear, if you're asking how to continue the next line in the console then you can use '' to denote that the next line is continued.

Comment: I just can't insert a big test into the console